# JMeter does not execute the next HTTP request

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to test some set of API's via JMeter, performance testing.

I have created a test plan and added all the necessary details,

here is how it looks like,

[image]

The **LB** which is the next request HTTP element, does not execute but not sure why ? below is a screenshot of it

[image]

This is the Thread Group configuration
[image]

This is the test plan configuration

[image]

I am using a Simple Controller.

JMeter Version: 5.5

View result tree

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all you dont have to add view results tree to each and every request - you can have global one to the threadgroup or test plan

By looking at your testplan - Can you tell us what kind of controller are you using ?
If you are using specific controller fr your logical needs - try first with simple controller

Comment: I am using a Simple controller just updated my question

Comment: Your sampler is getting executed - its not stopped. 

As I said the View results tree in the LB can show you the request been sent only for that particular sampler  - because its been placed as a child element for that particular sampler.


You need to remove the view results tree as a child element of each sampler and place it under thread group/testplan (single view results tree placed in global level can show you the request been sent for all samplers).

Comment: Only the AC is being executed by adding the "View Result Tree" to the thread group

Comment: can you share the screenshot of the testplan now?

Comment: The last screenshot in my question is the test plan. @rollno748

Comment: Nope, What i meant is the screen shot of your elements in the UI (the samplers and the listeners)

Comment: Please check my last screenshot now. Else we can move to chat ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252936/discussion-between-rollno748-and-oldcode).

Answer (score 0):

With [Simple Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Controller) JMeter should execute Samplers upside down at least once.

If JMeter doesn't run a particular Sampler most probably something is wrong with its configuration and we cannot tell what exactly is wrong without knowing what Sampler you're using and how it's set up.

Things you could try:

1. [Enabling debug logging for JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Controller), this way [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) will contain way more information regarding what's going on and most probably you will be able to identify the reason from  there
2. Try [running your test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```

   and once test is finished open the `result.jtl` in the View Results Tree listener and check whether it displays all the sample results or not

Comment: It is a [HTTP Request](https://octoperf.com/blog/2021/11/25/jmeter-http-requests/) sampler, invooking a REST based API with GET method